# Meteor & React | Login Logout navigation

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm new to meteor + react and I am wondering was is the correct way of displaying links if the user is logged in or logged out.

***Update:*** After logging out these links don't change reactively. They just sit on the page until I navigate somewhere else. Then they update.

```
LoggedOut = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <nav>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/login">Login</a>
                <a href="/register">register</a>
            </nav>
        )
    }
})

LoggedIn = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <nav>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/newProduct">New Product</a>
                <a className="text-danger" id="logout" href=""> Logout </a>
            </nav>
        )
    }
})

Nav = React.createClass({
    render() {
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            return(
                <LoggedIn />
            )
        }else{
            return(
                <LoggedOut />
            )
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved

1. I had to add a package to get reactive data from meteor: `meteor add react-meteor-data`
2. I had to add the mixins for the package  `mixins: [ReactMeteorData]`
3. I had to use getMeteorData(){} to return the state of the current user.

.

```
LoggedOut = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <nav>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/login">Login</a>
                <a href="/register">register</a>
            </nav>
        )
    }
})

LoggedIn = React.createClass({
    signOut: function(e) {
        Meteor.logout();
    },
    render() {
        return(
            <nav>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/newProduct">New Product</a>
                <a href="" onClick={this.signOut}> Logout </a>
            </nav>
        )
    }
})



Nav = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
    getMeteorData(){
        return{
            currentUser: Meteor.user()
        }
    },
    render() {
        let {currentUser} = this.data;
        if(currentUser){
            return(
                <LoggedIn />
            )
        }else{
            return(
                <LoggedOut />
            )
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you need to import anything specific to do it that way?